# Angular MatSort. Type is missing

Tags: angular, typescript

[appSort]="dataSource here is the problem:

Type 'MatTableDataSource' is missing the following properties from type 'ContactListEntry': i

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [appSort]="dataSource" data-order="desc" data-name="employeeId" mat-sort-header>ID</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let formular">{{formular.id}}</td>
            </ng-container>
```

´´´

```
export class Sort {

  private sortOrder = 1;
  private collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {
      numeric: true,
      sensitivity: "base",
  })

  constructor() { }

  public startSort(property, order, type = "") {
      if (order === "desc") {
          this.sortOrder = -1;
      }
      return (a, b) => {
          if (type === "date") {
              return this.sortData(new Date(a[property]), new Date(b[property]));
          } else {
              return this.collator.compare(a[property], b[property]) * this.sortOrder;
          }
      }
  }

  private sortData(a, b) {
      if (a < b) {
          return -1 * this.sortOrder;
      } else if (a > b) {
          return 1 * this.sortOrder;
      } else {
          return 0 * this.sortOrder;
      }
  }
}
```

´´´

```
import { Directive, Input, Renderer2, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactListEntry } from '../contact-list-entry';

import { Sort } from '../data-service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSort]'
})
export class SortDirective {


  @Input() appSort: ContactListEntry;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private targetElement: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener("click")

  sortData(){


    const sort = new Sort();

    const elem = this.targetElement.nativeElement;

    const order = elem.getAttribute("data-order");

    const type = elem.getAttribute("data-type");

    const property = elem.getAttribute("data-name");


    if(order === "desc"){
      this.appSort.sort(sort.startSort(property, order, type)); // 
      elem.setAttribute("data-order", "asc");
    } else {                                                          // Problem mit quick fix behoben!!!
      this.appSort.sort(sort.startSort(property, order, type)); //
      elem.setAttribute("data-order", "desc");
    }

  }
}
```

My Problem is that [appSort]="dataSource" is red and appSort cant be used. I want that appSort can be used so that the functions in appSort can be executed or that the array items can be sorted with Angular Material Sort.

Thanks for Help :)

Comment: Can you please clarify the issue you're experiencing?

Comment: My Problem is that i dont know which Variable by  [appSort]="..." i need to use that my programm work. I mean that I do not know which variable I have to write in there or I think I have to put my array variable in there, but it does not work.

Comment: oh I see. It sounds like you don't know what variable to put there because you are not actually using that variable inside the directive this means you don't need to put anything there just add the directive like this `appSort`

Comment: Do you mean that I should insert all the code from sort.directive.ts into object.component.ts or should I just import sort.directive.ts into object.component.ts?

Comment: what happens when you put `[appSort]=dataSource`. Is `appSort` value undefined in the `appSort` directive?

Comment: He shows me the error at appSort : Type 'MatTableDataSource<ContactListEntry>' is missing the following properties from type 'ContactListEntry': id, name, vorname, mobileNumber, and 6 more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238610/discussion-between-o-meekoh-and-max-flu).

Answer (score 0):

In your directive change

`@Input() appSort: ContactListEntry;`

to

`@Input() appSort: MatTableDataSource<ContactListEntry>;`

or in your template change

`[appSort]="dataSource"`

to:

`[appSort]="dataSource.data"`

and leave the directive as is.

Comment: [appSort]="dataSource.data"

@Input() appSort: MatTableDataSource;

I changed both once individually and then both. If I change both, I no longer have the error with [appSort] = "dataSource.data" but with @Input () appSort: MatTableDataSource ; and it says cannot find name MatTableDataSource

Comment: You cant change both `[appSort]=dataSource.data` AND `@Input() appSort: MatTableDataSource`. `dataSource.data` returns `ContactListEntry` so the type on `@Input()` has to match. Where `dataSource` returns `MatTableDataSource<ContactListEntry>` so the `@Input()` type has to match that. DId you do one or the other as explained?

Comment: Ja ich habe es zu [appSort]="dataSource.data" geändert und in sort.directive.ts @Input() appSort: ContactListEntry; so gelassen aber [appSorted] gibt das aus: Dem Typ 'ContactListEntry[]' fehlen die folgenden Eigenschaften vom Typ 'ContactListEntry': id, name, vorname, mobileNumber und 6 weitere.

Comment: Ok, now update your `@Input() appSort: ContactListEntry;` to `@Input() appSort: ContactListEntry[];`

Its just matching the return types here. I think that is your underlying issue.

Comment: First of all, I have no more mistakes. Thanks in advance for that :) But sorting the ITems from the array doesn't work

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I found the solution to the other problem :)

Comment: awesome! What was the issue?

Comment: i changed the formular.id to data.id